# php array to variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have got some data from My DB and I am trying to put it into variables I have tried allsorts and am really struggling to figure it out. could someone please point me in the right direction :-) This is what I have:

```
            <?php 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM location where unit_id = POG1;"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $act_unit_data = array();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $act_unit_data[] = $row;
            }
        }


print_r($act_unit_data);
```

This will print out:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [unit_id] => POG1 [unit_name] => Gazebo 1 [till_float] => 150 ) )
```

I have tried extracting `$act_unit_data` but cant echo any of what I thought the variables would be for example: `unit_id` please could someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: How did you extract it?

Comment: You're assigning rows of data to an array, so: `$act_unit_data[0]['unit_id']` you can see the two levels of the array in your output.

Comment: @Medhi I was using 'extract($act_unit_data);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here you're assigning row to the next element in your array

```
$act_unit_data[] = $row;
```

so you'd get `$act_unit_data[0]['unit_id']` for example.

```
$row['unit_id']
```

in your while loop will fetch you that data, and of course you can assign that:

`$unitId = $row['unit_id'];`

Comment: Important point to add: the variable `$row` already is an array. The last line of this answer hints this, but it took me several sleepless nights to actually understand this very issue, that I rather point it out even more to save one sleepless night :)

Comment: Fantastic it's all strting to make more sense thank you :-)